# How to set up local google app server in intellij 11

Tags: deployment, intellij-idea

I am trying to deploy my application to Google App Engine (GAE) through intellij 11 ultimate.

I have downloaded the GAE sdk and followed the instructions ([here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_app_engine.html)) on how to setup intellij properly.

The problem is when I try to add the local GAE to test my application I am getting

> Error: Application Server 'AppEngine Dev' is not configured

Intellij 11, GAE java-sdk-1.7.4

Error message and I am not sure what I am missing. [image]

Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you ignore this error? What happens when you click on the `Configure` button? Do you see the proper server configuration? Can you provide the screenshot showing the server configuration classpath?

Comment: Nothing!. Pressing to configure button does not take me to any configuration dialog (As expected). It just clicks. 

Ignoring the error and pressing OK just closes the window as if I pressed Cancel

Comment: There should be some exception in `idea.log`: `Help` | `Reveal Log in ...` You can try starting with the default settings after renaming [IDEA folders](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) and try [IDEA 11.1.5](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1228) or [IDEA 12](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like a bug. Only after deleting GAE facet I was able to click on the configure button in the Run/Debug Configuration. Once this was done I was able to add the facet and again.

Comment: That did not work for me. I've hit this many times now. This time I had to restart IntelliJ and then open up the Settings->Application Servers menu right after reboot. Then I was able to fix the issues. It is really annoying when that Configure button stops working. This bug was in IDEA 12 and is in 13.